# cannot insert None value in postgres using psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a database(postgresql) with more than 100 columns and rows. Some cells in the table are empty,I am using python for scripting so None value is placed in empty cells but it shows the following error when I try to insert into table.

```
"  psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "none" does not exist"
```

Am using psycopg2 as python-postgres interface............Any suggestions??

Thanks in advance......

Here is my code:-

```
list1=[None if str(x)=='nan' else x for x in list1];

cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO table VALUES %s""" %list1;
);
```

Comment: Python does *not* need to use `;` semicolons.

Comment: Does `list1` hold just **one** value? Or are you trying to use this for multiple insertions?

Answer (score 6):

Do not use `%` string interpolation, use [SQL parameters](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) instead. The database adapter can handle `None` just fine, it just needs translating to `NULL`, but only when you use SQL parameters will that happen:

```
list1 = [(None,) if str(x)=='nan' else (x,) for x in list1]

cursor.executemany("""INSERT INTO table VALUES %s""", list1)
```

I am assuming that you are trying to insert multiple rows here. For that, you should use the [`cursor.executemany()` method](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.executemany) and pass in a list of rows to insert; each row is a tuple with one column here.

If `list1` is just *one* value, then use:

```
param = list1[0]
if str(param) == 'nan':
    param = None

cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO table VALUES %s""", (param,))
```

which is a little more explicit and readable.